# Order by Array of documents in aggregation mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with documents like these

```
{
   "Day" : 1
   "Name" : "Fred",
   "Badges" : ["STAR", "FAST"]
}

{
   "Day" : 2
   "Name" : "Fred",
   "Badges" : ["STAR", "NEWBIE", "SLOW"]
}

{
   "Day" : 3
   "Name" : "Fred",
   "Badges" : ["STAR", "NEWBIE", "FAST"]
}


{
   "Day" : 1
   "Name" : "Frank",
   "Badges" : ["STAR","GO"]
}

{
   "Day" : 2
   "Name" : "Frank",
   "Badges" : ["STAR"]
}
```

I aggregated these documents for all month in order to return a statistic like this

```
{
  Name : "Fred"
  Badges : [{Name : "STAR", Count : 3}, 
            {Name : "NEWBIE", Count : 2}, 
            {Name : "FAST", Count : 2},
            {Name : "SLOW", Count : 1}
           ]
}
```

and the same thing for Frank.

```
{
  Name : "Fred"
  Badges : [{Name : "STAR", Count : 2}, 
            {Name : "GO", Count : 1}
           ]
}
```

I have a problem with the sort . 
How can I order for badge value STAR ? 
Could I change the aggregation query in order to produce different result ?

I think that a structure like this can be good solution  but I don't understand how to obtain it

```
 {Name : "Fred"
   STAR : 2
   GO : 1}
```

Thanks

Comment: Use $unwind command to iterate through elements of `Badges` array. Then you can do $project to extract counts per each badge value, then sort on that `STAR` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.a.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$Badges"}, 
{$group: {_id: {name: "$Name", badge: "$Badges"}, numberOfBadges: { $sum: 1}}},
{$project: {_id: 0,name: "$_id.name", badge: "$_id.badge", numberOfBadges:1, orderField:  {$cond: [{$eq: ["$_id.badge", "STAR"]}, "$numberOfBadges", 0]}}}, 
{$sort: {orderField:-1}}])
```

As far as I know you cannot have dynamic field names in aggregation framework so you can't have a field name as `STAR`. But you can make a trick by adding a new field to your document such as `orderField` and set the number of `numberOfBadges` to that document if the badge is `STAR`, otherwise set 0 to that field. Then sort on `orderField`.